# How to link to another part of the same page? (tabs issue)

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked before, and I know the answer but in my situation it's a bit different.

So the tab I want to link to that part has the code, e.g.

```
<li><a href="#portfolio" data-toggle="tab">portfolio</a></li>
```

And the part of the page has the code:

```
<a name="portfolio"></a>
```

But nothing happens when I click the tab. If I take the data-toggle="tab" bit out it works. But if I don't include it the tabs do not appear selected when I click them.

Here's a link to the entire page if needed: http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/PzoZPX

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the `data-toggle="tab"` that's breaking your code.

You're not using the bootstrap tabs, but ordinary anchor links. 
Adding `data-toggle="tab"` will trigger different functionality (done by the bootstrap js code) for those links.

Remove it and it'll work:
http://codepen.io/JasperZelf/pen/OXJQeg

Comment: That works, but my tabs don't stay selected when I remove 'data-toggle="tab"'. They change to the deep green color when you click them but then it goes back to the light green.

Comment: If you want anchor links to to have an active state, you should take a look at the "scrollspy" section: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/